# Creating an object array with a different type from an existing object array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

Using lambdas and LINQ in C#, I can create a new collection with a certain type based on a collection with a different type. For instance:

```
var array = new List<Foo> { new Foo { name = "John", age = "21", title = "Mr." } };
// I can then use the Select function to create a collection with a different type
var modifiedArray = array.Select(foo => new Bar { title = foo.Title });
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this in Javascript. I currently have:

```
var array = [{name: 'John', age: '21', title: 'Mr.'}];
var modifiedArray = [];

array.forEach(function(foo){
    modifiedArray.push({title: foo.title});
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```
var modifiedArray = array.map(function(x){ 
    return {title: x.title} 
});
```

Comment: That is the fastest I have EVER seen someone reply on Stack Overflow. Thank you so much!

Comment: @dimgl glad to have helped you :)

Comment: @dimgl: Note that `map` was added in ES5, so it's not in older browsers like IE8. It can readily be shimmed, though.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder this is for a Node.js backend script

Comment: @dimgl: Then you're fine.